# « Those aren't just home runs, those are moon shots » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, sport

> Those aren't just home runs, those are [moon shot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moon_shot#English)s... [ [sur Youtube](https://youtu.be/8sS73Z54xTo?t=7626) ]

On parle d'un [*coup de circuit*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_de_circuit) (au *baseball*) ayant une très haute trajectoire résultant en une très longue distance, et où la balle retombe souvent bien au delà de la clôture du champ, par opposition à une tel coup qui franchit à peine la clotûre ou à une « [chandelle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chandelle) » ([*pop-up ball*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pop-up#Noun)), très haute mais où la balle reste sur le terrain). Plus généralement le terme [*moon shot*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/moon_shot/596052) évoque le *lancement d'un vaisseau lunaire*.

Comment évoque-t-on un tel coup de circuit ou comment traduit-on la phrase ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans le domaine sportif, on utilise le verbe *satelliser* (mettre en orbite) pour dire "envoyer une balle qui part très loin du terrain." Le nom correspondant est satellisation ou mise en orbite. La connotation peut être négative, car au baseball c'est une bonne chose mais au foot ou au tennis pas vraiment...

Quant au terme *home run* du baseball, en français de France on l'emprunte simplement à l'anglais, comme attesté sur le site de l'Équipe, journal sportif de France.

On pourrait traduire par "ce ne sont pas des *home runs* ordinaires, ce sont des balles satellisées" ou des "balles mises en orbite".

Comment: Je trouve _mise en orbite_ ou même le participe passé de satelliser, plus usuel que _satellisation_ mais bien vu ! À bien y penser je pense que j'évoquerais même la _conquête de l'espace_ ou de la _lune_, probablement avec _parti pour_.

Comment: @suiiurisesse oui c'est vrai, changé pour "satellisé" au lieu de satellisation.

Answer (score 2):

Déjà en France nous utilisons beaucoup de terme anglais comme "home run". "Coup de circuit" est surtout, je pense, utilisé au Canada ou en suisse qui francise certains termes anglais. Tu peux donc sûrement utiliser "moon shot" en anglais dans le texte.

Sinon je ne connais pas le terme exact mais tu peux peut-être utiliser :

> coup  / frappe lunaire ou haut(e)

Dans d'autres sports, un coup qui envoie une balle en l'air est souvent un lob ou une chandelle comme au tennis, volley ou rugby. Mais chandelle semble être utilisé pour un coup qui ne dépasse pas le diamant et le lob pour l’abréviation de "left on base".

Comment: Je pense qu'une "frappe lunaire" serait comprise par la plupart des Français. C'est une métaphore assez simple à imaginer.
Un peu comme une "patate (de forain)" pour désigner un coup de poing assez fort.

Comment: Oui, le terme _coup de circuit_ est probablement du Qc (voir lien). Je comprends pour le terme technique à la limite, cependant je n'utilise pas des mots communs de l'anglais pour se substituer à l'imaginaire et aux métaphores de ma langue, je trouve que c'est faible. Je parle anglais depuis fort longtemps et je n'aurais même pas pu dire que _moon shot_ évoque un lancement lunaire en aérospatiale, prouvant par le fait même que ce genre de terme n'évoque rien en français, n'interpelle pas et n'est même pas compris naturellement, donc je ne n'utiliserais jamais. _Canon, flèche, fusée_ évoquent.

Comment: Avant de puiser dans le fonds linguistique pour des analogies recevables, on peut se demander s’il n’existerait pas déjà une terminologie en place (losange pour diamond, par exemple), auquel cas mieux vaut se l’approprier avant d’y ajouter sa touche personnelle. En parlant la même langue que ceux qui connaissent le baseball, on montre sa connaissance du sujet. **Tennis-pelouse** pour ce qui se joue à Wimbledon est linguistiquement possible, mais fautif ou au moins humoristique dans la terminologie de ce sport. Le ou la **moon shot** ne me semble pas recevable au Québec, du moins pas à ce jour.

Comment: Le lob aussi, comme la chandelle, il faut qu'il retombe dans le terrain. C'est un coup d'adresse visant à être suffisamment haut pour passer au-dessus du joueur adverse, mais pas si haut qu'il retombe en-dehors du terrain. Ça n'a rien à voir avec l'abréviation LOB qui est une statistique de baseball ni au concept du moonshot qui est un coup de force pure, où la balle part le plus loin possible.

Answer (score 2):

*Coup stratosphérique* est utilisé dans d'autres sports, par exemple le football ou le tennis, pour désigner un coup très puissant. Il me semble que cette expression pourrait convenir ici, en remplacement de *moon shot*.